# How to set local notification content to be the same as the content presented in the home screen when opened? [SWIFT]

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uilocalnotification

I am trying to recreate an existing motivational quote app as practice.

On this app, you get a notification which displays the contents, and if you click it the home page provides you with the rest of the quote (screenshots below). I have seen this type of app a lot – they all use collection views and the notification and homepage content always match.

I have tried mimicking this by setting up local notifications for the next 7 days to provide the user with a random quote from my array:

```
func configureNotifications() {
    let shuffled = quotes.shuffled()
    for i in 1...7 {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = “Daily quotes”
        content.body = shuffled[i].text

        let alertDate = Date().byAdding(days: i) // scheduled for next 7 days added
        
        var alertComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: alertDate)
        alertComponents.hour = 10
Etc
}

func updateQuoteHome() {

    guard let selectedQuote = quotes.randomElement() else {
        fatalError("Unable to read a quote.")
    }

    updateLabels(with: selectedQuote)
}
```

However, once the notification is clicked, or if the user just randomly opens the app, the content displayed is obviously completely different.

What is the method to link these two together – is it even possible with local notification or are these apps utilising push notifications?

Is there something about this in the documentation?

Thank you ~

[image: Notification]
[image: HomeScreen]

Answer (score 1):

You should use Push Notifications for this feature. If you have little or no backend experience you can use [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) and [Firebase Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging) to achieve this.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. But is this the only way this is achieved? How does push notifications allow the notification to match the content on the homescreen?

Comment: You can retrieve the notification content when the user taps it with the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, but I still would use push notifications since they are dynamic. You can't change a scheduled local notification, but a push notification content is completely dynamic. Source: https://medium.com/quick-code/local-notifications-with-swift-4-b32e7ad93c2